# How to implement One to many Relationship in Django RestFramework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here i have mentioned my model.py and serilaizers.py i want to use one to many concept here. And my expecting output like this.

**Expected output**

```
{
    "id": 1,        
    "product_name": "Rice",
    "description": "expired on 13-04-2018",
    "sales": "55",
    "cost": "55",
    "tax_details": [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/1/",
            'percentage': 10
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/3/",
            'percentage': 2
        }, {
            'id': 3,
            'tax_name': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tax/2/",
            'percentage': 05
        },
        ... 
    ],
}
```

**Models.py**

**TAX model**

This is main tax table here i will mension Tax name like(IGST,GST,VAT) it was an Dropdown.

**Product**

Here it consist of product details and i have mentioned in **Expected output**

**TaxProduct**

In this model the entered taxname and percentage should store separate model.

```
  class tax(models.Model)
      tax_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
      percentage = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

  class Taxproduct(models.Model):
      tax_name = ForeignKey(tax, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
      percentage = models.CharField(max_length = 3)

  class Product(models.Model):
      product_name =  models.CharField(max_length = 25)
      description = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
      category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
      sales = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
      cost = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
      tax_details = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

**Serializer**

```
  class TaxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
      model = Tax
      fields = ('id','tax_name', 'tax_percentage')
  class TaxproductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
      model = Taxproduct
      fields = ('id', 'tax_name', 'percentage')

  class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      tax_details = TaxproductSerializer(many=True, read_only = True)
  class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ('id', 'image','pro_name', 'description', 'sales', 'cost', 'tax_details')
```

so please tell me  how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to add one-to-many relation to your models. For this you need to add `ForeignKkey` field to `Taxproduct` model:

```
class Taxproduct(models.Model)
    tax_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    percentage=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This will add to `Product` model attribute [`taxproduct_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) which will return list of related taxes. To add it to serializer with different name (`tax_details` in your case) use field's [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tax_details = TaxproductSerializer(many=True,read_only=True, source='taxproduct_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','pro_name','description','sales','cost','tax_details')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it doesnt work.After trying in this way the output was like  {
        "id": 1,        
        "pro_name": "Dal",
        "description": "Expired on 02-11-2018",,
        "sales": "545",
        "cost": "6565",
    
    
        
    } except tax_details everything displayed.

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj can you add to your question updated models and serializer?

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj I mean code after you tried my answer.

Comment: **models.py**
class Product(models.Model):
 pro_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
 cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)
 tax_details= models.CharField(max_length=250)
 
class Taxproduct(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 percentage = models.CharField(max_length=3)
 product = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: **serializer.py**
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tax_details = TaxproductSerializer(many=True,read_only=True, source='taxproduct_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','pro_name','description','sales','cost','tax_details')

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj did you make `makemigrations` and `migrate` after add `ForeignKey` to the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169156/discussion-between-sudharsan-venkatraj-and-neverwalkaloner).